# Compute the Cardinality of the set $\{z \in \Bbb{Z}|z>-10, z^3<0\}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic

Compute the cardinality of the set $\{z \in \Bbb{Z} \mid z>-10, z^3<0\}$

We will also write this with the notation:  compute $\bigl|\{z \in \mathbb{Z} \mid z>-10, z^3<0\}\bigr|$.  (To show your work, makesure you show the set explicitly before telling us how many elements it has.)

If we're talking about all integers ($\Bbb{Z}$) including negatives. For the first part of $z > -10$. $z$ can only be up to $-9$ otherwise it would be greater then or equal to $-10$. But what would the cardinality be? Since the set would have $\{-9,-8,-7,-6...$ and so on till infinity?$\}$

And for the second part $z^3<0$. $z$ can only be $0$ otherwise anything else for $z^3$ would be grater then $0$. So the set would be $\{0\}$ with cardinality $1$?

Comment: Don’t all negative integers have negative cubes? So $z^3<0$ is equivalent to $z<0$, right?

Answer (score 6):

The integers satisfying $z>-10$ form the set $\{z \in \mathbb{Z} | z>-10\}=\{-9,-8,-7,...\}$.

The cube of a negative integer is negative, so the numbers satisfying $z^3<0$ are all the negative integers.

In the set $\{z \in \mathbb{Z}|z>-10, z^3<0\}$, you want both of these conditions to be true, so $$\{z \in \mathbb{Z}|z>-10, z^3<0\}=\{-9,-8,...,-2,-1\}$$ which has $9$ elements. That is, the cardinality is $9$.